# Arima - Plotting coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pmdarima

I need to predict the behavior of the graph using the ARIMA model. I found this code on the Internet, but it does not give the desired result in my case:

```
y = pm.datasets.load_wineind()
train, test = train_test_split(y, train_size=150)

# Fit your model
model = pm.auto_arima(train, seasonal=True, m=12)

# make your forecasts
forecasts = model.predict(test.shape[0])  # predict N steps into the future

# Visualize the forecasts (blue=train, green=forecasts)
x = np.arange(y.shape[0])
plt.plot(x[:150], train, c='blue')
plt.plot(x[150:], forecasts, c='green')
plt.show()
```

The task is to build a forecast graph based on coordinates (144 coordinates x and y) with ARIMA model that are written to a file and then used for forecasting. I send all the code for the general concept of the task:

```
import matplotlib
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pmdarima as pm
import pandas as pd
from pmdarima.model_selection import train_test_split
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame


class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = ""
        self.x = ""

    def Fill(self):
        n = 144
        xlist = []
        with open("x.txt", "w") as xlist:
            for i in range(n):
                xlist.writelines(str(i) + '\n')
        xlist.close()

        ylist = []
        with open("y.txt", "w") as ylist:
            for i in range(n):
                ylist.writelines(str(random.randint(1, 99)) + '\n')
        ylist.close()


     def Screen(self):
        n = 144
        x = np.array([])
         with open("x.txt") as xlist:
            for line in xlist:
                 x = np.loadtxt(xlist.readlines(int()))
                 self.fx = x

        y = np.array([])
        with open("y.txt") as ylist:
            for line in ylist:
                y = np.loadtxt(ylist.readlines(int()))
                self.fy = y
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()

    def Arima(self):
        with open('y.txt', 'r') as infile, open('y.csv', 'w') as outfile:
            stripped = (line.strip() for line in infile)
            lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerows(lines)

        y = []
        with open('y.csv') as f:
            for line in f:
                y = np.loadtxt(f.readlines(int()))


        train, test = train_test_split(y, train_size=140)

        model = pm.auto_arima(train, seasonal=True, m=12)

        forecasts = model.predict(test.shape[0])

        x = np.arange(y.shape[0])
        plt.plot(x[:140], train, c='blue')
        plt.plot(x[140:], forecasts, c='green')
        plt.show()


gra = Graph()
gra.Fill()
gra.Screen()
gra.Arima()
```

I assume that I need to make my own dataset, where the data for forecasting will come from, but I don't know how to do it.

This program makes these charts:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you are looking for? Do the forecasts just look bad? or is something not being plotted as you expect?

Comment: Added an approximate graph view to the question